# Preprocessing data before transforming it into XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, preprocessor, transform

I am using JAXB to save my objects to XML. I have one problem with this though: One of my classes has a String

```
myclass.getFilePath() // returns an absolute file path
```

which represents an absolute file path. Before writing this file path to an XML file, I want to relativize it, so I need some kind of preprocessing on my getter. Is that possible using JAXB?

I know I could modify my class and add `getRelativePath()` and `setBasePath()` but I would prefer to somehow transform my file path and only do this when exporting to XML.

**Update:**

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyConverter.class)
```

should be close to the solution, though I still need a way to pass in an argument (the base path for the relative path) - any hint on this?

**Update 2**

Probably this does the job: [Anyway to pass a constructor parameter to a JAXB Adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454673/anyway-to-pass-a-constructor-parameter-to-a-jaxb-adapter) Will check it now.

Comment: The approach you included in update 2 is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to what you want, just an idea

```
class Adapter extends XmlAdapter<String, File> {
    @Override
    public File unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(File v) throws Exception {
        return v.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}

public class Test1 {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter.class)
    File file = new File("xxx");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXB.marshal(new Test1(), System.out);
    }
}
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test1>
    <file>D:\workspace1\x\xxx</file>
</test1>
```