# EnumSet and JAXB

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, enumset

I'd like to marshall/unmarshall an object containing an EnumSet field. EnumSet has no constructors so I'm trying to write an adapter for it. Of course, it should work for any EnumType so I'm trying to use generics but I don't know the exact EnumType during unmarshalling. Am I doing it the wrong way? Is there some straightforward solution?

intended usage:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EnumSetAdapter.class)
private final EnumSet<MyEnumType> status;
```

and my attempt looks like:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class EnumSetAdapter<E extends Enum<E>> extends XmlAdapter<String, EnumSet<E>> {
    
    private static final String DELIMITER = ",";

    @Override
    public EnumSet<E> unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] enumNameArr = v.split(DELIMITER);
        //how to get the actual EnumType here?
        List<E> enumList = Stream.of(enumNameArr).map(str -> E.valueOf(!!! enumType !!!, str))...;
        EnumSet<E> resultEnumSet = EnumSet.copyOf(enumList);
        return resultEnumSet;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(EnumSet<E> v) throws Exception {
        return (v == null) ? null : v.stream().map(e -> e.name()).collect(Collectors.joining(DELIMITER));
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer...

The reason you cannot do something like `E.valueOf(...)` is because `E` is not a concrete type; it's just a type variable, and because of type erasure, at runtime it's not known what the actual type is that `E` stands for.

You would need the `Class<E>` object that specifies the type of the actual enum, but the problem is that it's not easy to get this in an `XmlAdapter`. For example like this:

```
public class EnumSetAdapter<E extends Enum<E>> extends XmlAdapter<String, EnumSet<E>> {

    private static final String DELIMITER = ",";

    private final Class<E> enumClass;

    public EnumSetAdapter(Class<E> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    @Override
    public EnumSet<E> unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] enumNameArr = v.split(DELIMITER);
        List<E> enumList = Stream.of(enumNameArr).map(str -> Enum.valueOf(enumClass, str)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return EnumSet.copyOf(enumList);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(EnumSet<E> v) throws Exception {
        return (v == null) ? null : v.stream().map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.joining(DELIMITER));
    }
}
```

**Problem:** JAXB is going to instantiate your `EnumSetAdapter` which does not give you the chance to pass the constructor parameter. So using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EnumSetAdapter.class)` won't work.

Possible solutions: See [Anyway to pass a constructor parameter to a JAXB Adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454673/anyway-to-pass-a-constructor-parameter-to-a-jaxb-adapter)

One possible, but clunky solution would be to create an adapter for each specific type of enum, that extends `EnumSetAdapter` and that passes the appropriate value to its superclass constructor. For example:

```
public class MyEnumTypeAdapter extends EnumSetAdapter<MyEnumType> {
    public MyEnumTypeAdapter() {
        super(MyEnumType.class);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyEnumTypeAdapter.class)
private final EnumSet<MyEnumType> status;
```

Disadvantage: You would need a class for each enum type.

See the question I linked to above for other possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! That's what I was afraid of. I was even thinking about encoding the class name of the actual enum to the value String during marshalling and using reflection while unmarshalling but that would be sooo dirty.

Comment: I'd add that this is linked to this issue : https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/234

Comment: Thanks for finding that @LaurentSchoelens, it's an issue that has been open since 2006 , so I'd not bet on this getting fixed anytime soon...

Comment: Some of them were fixed recently in 4.0.4 version of jaxb-ri and backported in 2.3.9. If it's feasible in an easy way, may be we could provide a PR for this one 

Comment: I managed to make jaxb-ri 4.0.5-SNAPSHOT evolved to support `EnumSetAdapter` as defined in the answer but also keep `MyEnumTypeAdapter` XmlJavaTypeAdapter working  Still working on it but maybe I'll be able to provide a PR for this soon. Then it'll need review and approval for merging into 4.0.5 milestone, and event go into 2.3.10 backported. I'll comment with PR link when provided.